Kids show about two robots isolated on a planet
I have seen this show back in the 80s.
It is in color. The characters spoke English (probably British English).
In each episode, they appear on a planet full of junk. (Maybe it is Earth after an apocalyptic incident). They are two lonely robots (or at least they are made up of various appliances, such as a sewing machine, etc.)
One of the characters always asks: "What is this object?" that he finds in the junk yard.
The other one will always answer AS IF he knew what it is and what it was used for, but he will be making things up and the point of the show is to make children point out how wrong the other robot/character is.
Can you identify the name of the show?

Possibly the rather forgotten CP & Qwikstitch from 1985. From a site (that also has a clip):

This animation series tells the story of two robots living on the planet Junkus Minor. This is where all the old and broken machines from throughout the galaxy end up. In the first episode 'Robots Come to Life' C-P describes to Qwikstitch his memory of humans. Amongst the junk is an old television, C-P explains how he was modelled on John Wayne and Paul Newman.

This also possibly answers this Sci-Fi.SE question; I posted it there too. 


Wow.. Amazing... That's it... Thanks
